# command only does one function

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using tkinter to create a gui and I'm trying to get my code to delete Buttons, but the "command" doesn't seem to be able to do more than one function

```
label1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="hello world", padx=50, pady=50, command=hello_world, fg="black", bg="yellow")
label2 = tkinter.Button(root, text="hello there", padx=50, pady=50, command=hello_there, fg="black", bg="green")
base = tkinter.Button(root, text="Return", padx=50, pady=50, command=label2.destroy and label1.destroy, fg="black", bg="red")
```

when i try to execute the command, only the last command is actually executed

Comment: Just define a function that execute the two functions you want the button to trigger and use it as the button's command.

Comment: Well you only give it one function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply define an intermediate function that runs both functions. See a small example below

```py
import tkinter as tk

def func1():
    print("Executed function 1")

def func2():
    print("Executed function 2")

def combined_func():
    func1()
    func2()

root = tk.Tk()
btn = tk.Button(root, text='My button', command=combined_func)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You could also define a lambda with a tuple containing each of the functions you need to run, if you do not want to create an intermediate function. That would look like this

```py
tk.Button(root, text='My button', command=lambda: (func1(), func2()))
```